# How many 20-vertex 2-connected 5-regular non-Hamiltonian graphs are there?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs, nauty

As for the question in title, I attempted to use `nauty` to obtain them, but it has been running on my computer for nearly three days without producing any results.

```
./geng 20 -C  -d5 -D5 |  ./hamheuristic >20_5_noh.txt
```

I haven't seen any sequences for the number of 2-connected 5-regular graphs, otherwise, I would have some estimation of the required running time.

Perhaps there are too many graphs to be generated, and I'm not sure how to stop the program after finding a certain number of them. It might be more efficient to directly utilize C programming in this case.

I have a feeling that there won't be many graphs I desire. From the theorem below, it is clear that a  $2$-connected 5-regular non-Hamiltonian graph has at least 20 vertices.

> Let $P$ denote the Petersen graph, and let $P^{\prime}$ denote the
> graph obtained from $P$ by replacing one vertex $v$ of $P$ by the
> complete graph $K_3$ and making each vertex of the $K_3$ adjacent to a
> distinct neighbor of $v$.  Hilbig proved the following theorem:

**Theorem 1.** (See Hilbig [1].) If $G$ is a 2-connected $k$-regular graph on at most $3 k+3$ vertices and $G \notin\left\{P, P^{\prime}\right\}$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

[1] F. Hilbig, Kantenstrukturen in nichthamiltonschen Graphen, Ph.D. thesis, Technische Universität Berlin, 1986.

The existence is not a problem (see the following graph, due to Misha Lavrov in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731551/find-a-minimum-2-connected-5-regular-non-hamiltonian-graph/4731924#4731924)), but I'm uncertain about the amount of time it would take to find all the desired graphs.

[image]

Comment: There are already more than 2 billion 5-regular graphs on 16 vertices (http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/reggraphs.html#CRG) so you will never solve this by exhaustive search.  It is a nice challenge problem though.

Comment: @GordonRoyle Thank you very much. Wow, It seems that brute force enumeration is indeed not a feasible approach. By the way, I  would like to mention that your  website (e.g., https://school.maths.uwa.edu.au/~gordon/data.html) seems to be currently inaccessible. Are those data no longer publicly available?

Comment: @LCZhang My university no longer supports personal web sites and I have not yet decided on a suitable alternative.

Comment: @GordonRoyle  Oh, I see. It's not clear whether GitHub would be a suitable alternative solution.

Comment: If I understand https://oeis.org/A165626 correctly, the number of $5$-regular graphs on $20$ vertices is 4,221,456,120,848,125.

Comment: @L.C.Zhang: Should the connectivity in your question be exactly 2?

Comment: @kabenyuk That's not necessarily the case.  However, if we restrict the  connectivity to be exactly 2, I am still  happy to see some results if possible.

Comment: I made 100 million random 5-regular graphs on 20 vertices and they were all hamiltonian.  So there might be a reasonable number of non-hamiltonian ones altogether but I don't know how to find them. The graphs which are exactly 2-connected could be made by joining the pieces together, but that would be difficult as there is probably a very large number.

Comment: Still no non-hamiltonian graphs in the first 2 billion random 5-regular graphs.  I'll stop there.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay I bet essentially all of the graphs you constructed are (at least) 3-connected. Finding a 3-connected 5-regular non-hamiltonian graph on 20 vertices would be a counterexample to a 1996 conjecture of Jackson, Li and Zhu which asserts that a 3-connected $k$-regular graph on at most $4k$ vertices is hamiltonian. My best guess is that all the non-hamiltonian ones have a 2-vertex cutset and probably look basically the same as the one above. It is possible to move a few edges around to get some non-isomorphic ones but nothing interesting.

Comment: Or a 1-vertex cutset, yes.